# How to get specific geometric properties of a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I am currently styling a `tcolorbox`. For that, I plan to use a boxed title that should be shifted. For that, ideally relative lengths can be used to remain versatile.

The documentation mentions `\tcboxedtitleheight` that is ideal for shifting in y direction. However, there does not seem to be good accessible properties for the width (there is `\tcbtextwidth` which I currently use as a workaround).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Define base style
\tcbset{stdbox/.style 2 args={
    enhanced,
    % A bit of indent to further distinguish from normal text
    left skip=\textwidth/20,
    colback=#1!10!white,
    colframe=#1!50!black,
    colbacktitle=#1!50!black,
    title=#2,
    % Bold title
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxed title style={size=small},
    % yshift* combines yshift and yshifttext
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=\tcbtextwidth/20,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}
  }
}
% Define boxes based on the base style
\newtcolorbox{examplebox}[1]{stdbox={blue}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{examplebox}{Test}
    Test
\end{examplebox}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, one could also access the other writable properties like `/tcb/width` etc.

Maybe this is already possible. I am not that experienced in LaTeX.

Comment: it would be nice to have a sketch of what is the expected result

Comment: I have added an example now. Basically, I want to use `/tcb/width` instead of `\tcbtextwidth` for `xshift`. Possibly also other properties of the box like margins.

Comment: You should give a MWE and explain the features expected because maybe there is an existing easy solution.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your "examplebox".

Comment: I have extended the code to have a MWE as requested.